# java response json fora de ordem

Tags: java, json, api, rest, order

Galera eu estou fazendo uma API em java para ser consumida por Excel.
Eu estou fazendo um select do banco trazendo as colunas na ordem certa,
porem quando chega no Excel chega em uma ordem meio louca.

Eu também fiz um método com:

```
Class.forName("className").getDeclaredMethods.getName();
```

Para pegar os os nomes dos métodos "get" destas classe de entidade (ex: Pessoa, Cliente) e estes nomes estão vindo fora de ordem também. Estão vindo com a mesma ordem das colunas no json.

tem alguma forma de fazer o

```
Class.forName("className").getDeclaredMethods.getName();
```

mantendo a ordem dos métodos da classe?
e manter a ordem do select no json?

Answer (score 1):

A ordem dos métodos no `Class.forName("className").getDeclaredMethods();` não é bem definida. Veja isso no [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--):

> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

Traduzindo:

> Os elementos no array retornado não estão ordenados em nenhuma ordem particular.

Assim sendo, você não pode confiar na ordem que isso vai trazer os métodos. Logo, a melhor forma é ordená-los explicitamente por algum critério bem definido. O nome do método seria uma ideia inicial, mas visto que pode haver métodos sobrecarregados (com o mesmo nome), então pode-se usar o [`toGenericString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#toGenericString--) para diferenciá-los:

```
public static List<Method> listMethods(Class<?> someClass) {
    List<Method> m = Arrays.asList(someClass.getDeclaredMethods());
    m.sort((m1, m2) -> {
        int c = m1.getName().compareTo(m2.getName());
        if (c != 0) return c;
        return m1.toGenericString().compareTo(m2.toGenericString());
    });
    return m;
}
```